# predict as multi regression model and lapply to cav

Tags: r

What I want to try is,

there are 10 fitting models, and implement to each vector and apply the result in one CSV file.

the dateset<test> like this

| content | undesirable | desirable | user_1 | ... | user_10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.00 | 2.77 | 0.11 |  | NA |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5000 | 2.50 | 2.11 | NA |  | 0.12 |

and I did as below to make 10 model

```
formulas = paste0("user_", 1:10, " ~ undesirable + desirable")
models = lapply(formulas, \(x)lm(as.formula(x), data = test))
```

and I want to repeat below to take the result 10 times,

: take each user's NA value to predict

```
user_1_na = test[is.na(test$user_1), c('user_1', 'undesirable', 'desirable')]
pred_user_1 = predict(models[[1]], newdata = u_1_na)
...

user_10_na = test[is.na(test$user_10), c('user_10', 'undesirable', 'desirable')]
pred_user_10 = predict(models[[10]], newdata = u_10_na)
```

and save the result in the csv file

I am not sure how to convert the result to dafa frame

```
which(result1 == max(result1))
max(result1)

# the result will be
V2719                         
615.0000000   0.8519751

...
which(result10 == max(result10))
max(result10)



f_result = which(result1 == max(result1))
f_result[2] = max(result1)
f_result
```

The result I try to make is

| user | user_1 | ... | user_10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| content_number | V2719 | ... | V#### |
| rating | 0.8519751 | ... | 0.#### |

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

We can perform all the lm's at once by using a matrix of dependent variables on the left hand side.  Using the built-in anscombe data frame

```
lm(cbind(y1, y2, y3, y4) ~ ., data = anscombe)
```

giving:

```
Call:
lm(formula = cbind(y1, y2, y3, y4) ~ ., data = anscombe)

Coefficients:
                   y1        y2        y3        y4      
(Intercept)   4.33291   6.42255   2.30291   1.96345
x1            0.45073   0.37327   0.52564   0.07691
x2                 NA        NA        NA        NA
x3                 NA        NA        NA        NA
x4           -0.09873  -0.25345   0.05182   0.53836
```